# Нужно исключить из массива некоторые элементы

Tags: javascript

Реализована фильтрация с помощью функции, необходимо, чтобы данная функция исключала элементы из массива. Я понимаю, что тут решение в одну строку, но я просто запутался, через find пробовал, вроде работает, но не проходит проверку.

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, '8', 'some str', true, NaN];
const notArray = arr =>  {
      return function(x) {
        return arr.includes(x) // не понимаю, что тут еще нужно подставить
      }
    };

console.log(arr.filter(notArray([1, 2, 3, 10, 99, null]))); // [4, 5, 6, 7, '8', 'some str', true, NaN]
```

Comment: "чтобы данная функция исключала элементы из массива" --- надеюсь не надо играть  в угадайку и вы скажите какие именно?

Comment: из примера вообще не ясно что происходит и причём тут фильтр который в себя принимает функцию от функции

Comment: Забыл объявить массив, исправил

Comment: "чтобы данная функция исключала элементы из массива" --- надеюсь не надо играть в угадайку и вы скажите какие именно?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, те, которые передал в параметре :)

Comment: @Grundy мммммм..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сейчас из исходного массива выбираются те элементы, которые **есть в массиве**, который передали в функцию `notArray`

Так как нужно выбирать элементы, которых **нет в массиве** - достаточно инвертировать условие

```
return !arr.includes(x) // проверяем что элемента нет.
```

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, '8', 'some str', true, NaN];
const notArray = arr => {
  return function(x) {
    return !arr.includes(x);
  }
};

console.log(arr.filter(notArray([1, 2, 3, 10, 99, null]))); // [4, 5, 6, 7, '8', 'some str', true, NaN]
```